# Error opening .vcd file. No such file or directory

Tags: verilog, icarus, gtkwave

My Verilog code is stored in `C:\FA`. There are three files:

```
FA.v, fa.vvp, TM_FA.v
```

I followed my book steps.

1. iverilog -o fa.vvp
2. vvp fa.vvp
3. finish
4. getwave fa.vcd &

When I use `getwave fa.vcd &` to simulate it, and then it shows:

```
Error opening  .vcd file 'fa.vcd'.
Why: No such file or directory
```

I firstly use Icarus and GTKwave, then I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add code in your Verilog testbench to explicitly tell `iverilog` to create a VCD file.  [The iverilog documentation states](https://iverilog.fandom.com/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_debug_a_Verilog_design_with_Icarus_-_there_is_no_built_in_waveform_viewer_like_Mentor.3F):

```
// Do this in your test bench

initial
 begin
    $dumpfile("test.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,test);
 end
```